# Is this lojban sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, lojban

Is "ta se klama" grammatically correct?
Could I say "That is gone to" in lojban, without adding a zo'e to my sentence?
Or would it have to be "That is gone to by something"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zo'e in Lojban is always implied when any place of a selbri isn't filled. You can use zo'e when you want to explicitly note that there is a "something", but it's not necessary.

So, ta se klama is grammatically correct, and would mean "That is gone to", as you said, or equivalently "Someone/something has gone there".